# what is different between @In(injected) and @Out(outjected) in SEAM

Tags: java, seam, seam2, seam-gen

I read in many book but still i did't understand what is the main difference between  @In(injected) and @Out(outjected), i am only aware with @In(injected) , i don't know where to use @Out(outjected) so please explain me with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand:

- @In(jection) - this injects the object from the "component pool" just before flow enters the class.
- @Out(jection) - is what happens at the end of the flow, just after the flow leaves the class, the component object is retained in the "component pool" for later use.

HTH